# Thunderblade and Great Thunderblade respawn areas

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I have a great thunderblade that is really good for stunning enemies such as silver bokoblins. I know a way that may be able to repair it, but I want to know if there are areas where they might respawn.

Comment: You can't repair items in this game, at all. If you're thinking about the octoroks/rusty weapon trick, that works *only* for rusty weapons, not anything else.

Comment: If you want more elemental weapons, the best place to go is the colosseum to the southwest of hyrule field

Comment: @Pyritie Should've posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The stalnox in Hickaly Woods drops a Thunderblade, and the one in the Hyrule Castle dungeon drops a Great Thunderblade.

Further reading:

- http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Thunderblade
- http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Thunderblade

Answer (score 4):

Thunderblades can also respawn in the Coliseum, just north of the Great Plateau.  See [my answer about where to get frost blades](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/312134/where-can-frostblades-respawn/312173#312173).  The same answer applies for Thunder Blades (+ spear) and fire weapons as well.

Comment: This was already mentioned in a comment above. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311884/thunderblade-and-great-thunderblade-respawn-areas#comment442727_311884

Comment: @n_palum But comments can vanish any time and are unfit to act as answers.

Comment: 1) they spelled "Coliseum" wrong making it harder to find on a map, and 2) my answer on the other question has a helpful graphic.  This is still better as an answer.

Comment: Fair enough then, but Coliseum and Colosseum are both valid words (I'm not sure how the game spells it)

Comment: @n_palum look at the picture on my other answer, the game spells it "Coliseum".  I'm not debating the best spelling of the word, I'm saying it is easier to find it if you are looking for the same spelling.