# Where can frostblades respawn?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I know that there are shrines that have a frostblades in chests. I also know that there is one in a labyrinth and in the Coliseum. Except I don't have the Coliseum unlocked. So is there a mini boss/monster somewhere that drops the frostblade?

Comment: What do you mean you "don't have the Colosseum unlocked"?

Comment: I don't have the area and I am not very high level in the game and I heard that there are high level enemies

Comment: Even if you can't see it on the map and you're low level you can still go to the Coliseum for loot; also unless you're playing on Master Mode enemies scale rather reasonably so they shouldn't even be that high of a level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Coliseum is the best place to get elemental weapons, and you don't need to unlock it as you seem to think.  I've included a picture from this interactive map:
https://www.zeldadungeon.net/breath-of-the-wild-interactive-map/
[image: A map of part of the world in Breath of the Wild showing the Coliseum]
You can see the Coliseum ruins near the middle of the map (marked by the bow and arrow icon).  The Great Plateau is near the bottom middle as a reference point, and the stable shown on the left/top part is the Outskirt Stable.  Just go into that Coliseum and have at it.

Warning about entering that area:

> There is a Lynel at the bottom.  If you aren't prepared to fight it, I recommend not using the front door (north side).  Climb up over the walls or mountain, and enter from the top.  There are 3 floors above the Lynel.  Each floor contains enemies with frost, lightning, and fire weapons respectively.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer when the question specifically asks where to find frost weapons **not** in the Coliseum?

Comment: @BlueBarren the OP asks where they can be acquired other than the Coliseum because they were under the mistaken impression that the Coliseum needs to be unlocked.  I pointed out that it doesn't, and where it is.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but shouldn't we be answering questions based on what user's question asks not what you think they need an answer to?

Comment: @BlueBarren in general yes, but the user's question was based on a false premise.  Addressing that made the correct answer much simpler for them and everyone who checks this question in the future.

Comment: But what about the people looking to find frost weapons not in the Coliseum?  They will come across this question and realize it doesn't give them an answer.

Comment: There is no difference getting frost weapon from the Coliseum or anywhere else.  They are all identical.  If you want one, this is the easiest method by far.  If you want one "not in the Coliseum", then you are making your life more difficult than it needs to be.  Sure there are tons of less simple and efficient ways to accomplish this task, but if your end goal is just to get a frost weapon, there is no reason to not do it this way.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple alternatives to find that weapon apart from the Coliseum.

- Rewards in two other shrines: **Jitan Sa'mi Shrine** and **Namika Ozz shrine**.
- They are carried by **Lizalfos** on some places but a particular spot is in the Hebra region, one of those **big skull camps** with monsters. one of the Lizalfos carries one (As shown in the map below)
  [image: Hebra map]

**Note**: Haven't included intentionally any spoilers such as the location of the Shrines or any additional information on the map.

The image was edited from this original source. https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DLT1ELm0Irg/maxresdefault.jpg